# Hall element - Hall effect sensor identification needed (40 year old component)

Tags: sensor

Attached is a pic of a Hall element/Hall effect sensor from a 40 year old motor with PLL speed stability in the motor controller.  The Hall sensor on top is the original.  The new one below it is one that replaced it in 2003.  I am looking for any info anyone might have such as part number, manufacturer, case type, etc. for both in the picture. The motor was made by TDK about 40 years ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to investigate the controller in order to figure out the needed specs, and find a modern substitute.

Hall sensors are mostly all the same; just figure out the controller needs! So that 15 years from now you'll be able to replace the thing again without having to find a 55 years old part!